# Inconsistent VAT calculation in invoices created via Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I am creating invoices via the API which typically have a number of line items. Xero occasionally calculates the total with 1p different to what I am expecting.

What makes this really strange is if I open up the invoice in Xero and click edit... Xero changes it's mind and calculates the total correctly. The problem seems to occur when the line item has a discount. I have a line item with unit price £2,120.44 with a 10% discount. In the created invoice Xero calculates the amount as £1,908.39 which is rounding down from 1908.396. If I click edit the amount changes to £1,908.40 which is rounding up as expected.

This seems to be a bug where it's behaving inconsistently :-(

Comment: When I send an invoice from my point of sale software to Xero, I specify the VAT on each line. I didn't originally, but we had a few circumstances (the exact details of which I forget now) where the invoice total rounded a different way. Calculating VAT on each line and sending it across seemed the easiest way to make the two systems agree.

Comment: thanks droopsnoot will try giving that a go